# EMV card & APDU command to get the track 2

Tags: emv

I trying to get the PAN from my card. I read a lot of topic about that, but I still understand :'(

I understand I have to find the AID I tried :

`00A404000E315041592E5359532E4444463031`

Thats works, but I don't really get some interesting informations ... If I correctly understand I have to find the 94 Application File Locator (AFL) (16 Byte) to be able to read the data...

Do i have to try another AID until I find the AFL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Track2(tag 57) is usually returned in in response to READ RECORDs. To issue READ RECORDs you need to get the AFL first. AFL is returned in response to GET PO. 
In VISA contactless you will get track in GET PO itself and you will get AFL only if ODA is required.

Comment: Thanks ! Using the AID of my card, im just able to get this data ...
6F File Control Information (FCI) Template,
84 Dedicated File (DF) Name
A5 File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
50 Application Label
87 Application Priority Indicator
9F38 Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL)

Comment: Proceed to GET PO